# Selecting features within bounding box using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, features, extents, select-by-location

What is the best way within QGIS to select all of the features within a rectangular bounding box? Is it necessary to create a separate layer with the box, then to use the intersection tool within vector research -> select by location?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you can do rectangular bounding box selection with **default selection** tool with mouse/touchpad down + hold and move + up (there is also selection tool by polygon, freehand and elipse)

You can also use **Select features using expression** and make selection by comparing feature Geometry xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax to your extent - minimum, maximum coordinates.

And yes, there is also tool you already mentioned - *Vector - Research Tools - Select by location...*

All depends what you want to achieve.